# Cufon issues with cyrillic characters

Tags: javascript, html, cufon

I'm using cufon on this site: http://whatismycar.com/
Everything works fine, but I've started to translate the site and now I need cyrillic characters in my cufon boxes. I've generated the font by my own and it DOES support cyrillic characters. However when I have cyrillic characters in my boxes the text box appears blank. I think there might be a problem with the encoding somewhere but I have no idea how to fix it. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the checkbox for :

> **[Cyrillic Alphabet](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/#iglyphs_cyr)**
>   For a complete list, see Cyrillic characters in Unicode. (up to 432 glyphs)

When generating your cufon font?  Often if you keep your font small you don't add the extras, and that's what you might be missing, which results in lack of characters.